# How to bind a model property (from controller) without it firing validation right away?

Tags: ember.js

I have a simple model backed controller with a simple validation on fullname. I added the validation to the models error computed property as shown below. It' works great except that this computed property is "fired" right away showing the "please enter a username" error right when the form is rendered.

Question is -how *should* I so this to get the nice computed property/2 way data bound property and error message but ... something that won't fire right away (instead waiting for the user to type something first).

```
var UserController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    actions: {
        submit: function() {
            //verify model is legit ... transitionToRoute if so
        }
    }
});

var User = Ember.Object.extend({
    enteredUsername: "",
    username: function() {
        var enteredUsername = this.get("enteredUsername");
        return enteredUsername.trim();
    }.property("enteredUsername"),
    usernameError: function() {
        var username = this.get("username");
        if (!username) {
            return "please enter a username";
        }
    }.property("username")
});

{{input type="text" value=model.enteredUsername}}
<span class="input-error">{{model.usernameError}}</span>
```

Comment: Just and idea, you probably should check if the property is `dirty`..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @Sisir said, you may need to have some sort of variable to check if the model value is dirty. Here is a way to get that implemented. Basically a model property will comprise of a `value` and `isDirty` property. So `enteredUsername` will be

```
enteredUsername: {
  value: '',
  isDirty: false
}
```

Your modified code will look like

```
var User = Ember.Object.extend({
  enteredUsername: {
    value: '',
    isDirty: false
  },

  username: function() {
    var value = this.get("enteredUsername.value").trim();

    //Once dirty is set, then dont reset.
    if(!this.get('enteredUsername.isDirty')) {
        this.set('enteredUsername.isDirty', value.length > 0);
    }

    return value;
  }.property('enteredUsername.value'),

  usernameError: function() {
    var username = this.get("username");
    var isDirty = this.get('enteredUsername.isDirty');
    if (!username && isDirty) {
      return "please enter a username";
    }
  }.property('username', 'enteredUsername.isDirty')
});
```

[**Here is a working demo.**](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/derege/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Awesome! this also (almost) solves my basic dirty tracking problem (using a simple identity map - not ember-data)