# How to achieve dirty or pristine checking on ember forms

Tags: ember.js, ember-validations

I often have to show validation icons on forms when using ember. However when using ember validations there is immediate feedback on if the form is valid. However I do not want to display the icons until at least the user has attempted to fill out a temperate then lost focus.  How would I achieve this automatically?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28038852/how-to-bind-a-model-property-from-controller-without-it-firing-validation-righ

Comment: @blessenm thanks but that is not ember validations

Comment: I really liked this implementation: http://www.teamrarebit.com/blog/2015/02/14/ember-inline-validation-errors where you create a component encapsulating the input field and error text and show the error text only if focus-out is triggered on the input field. ... I also had one approach, where I triggered a css class on the container of the whole form, on submit/save, to show all errors only when the submit/save button was hit.

Comment: shameless plug - I wrote this library to achieve exactly the UX you mention. https://github.com/toranb/ember-cli-simple-validation and here is a demo to see it in action http://emberjs.jsbin.com/gobemu/2/ (the only part that isn't aligned w/ your requirements is that focusOut won't fire the validation -only changing the value in the input will fire it)

Comment: thanks @ToranBillups I will check it out, right now I need the focus out to fire.